# Count (column 3) and sum(values of column 4) based on a unique combination of column 1 and column 2;

Tags: sql-server

Aim: 
Count (column 3) and  sum(values of column 4) based on a unique combination of column 1 and column 2; 
Is this possible in one SQL statement? If yes, what is the precise syntax?

Explanation: Consider a table with 4 columns like

[image]

The task is to count all Id_Indiv and to sum up the weight values depending on the 4 existing unique combination of genus & species.

The desired output is

[image]

If possible to create the desired output in one sql statement, it could read somewhat like:

```
SELECT genus, species, count(ID_Indiv) as NoOfIndiv, sum(weight)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           genus,
           species 
      FROM  TableName
)W
group by  genus, species;
```

Note: there might be more than 50 possible Genus*species combinations, and we do not know if/when new combinations will come up. Thus I cannot predefine the combination, but the statement has to identfy them.

Please, could somebody help me with the exact Sql statement?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What do you use nested `SELECT` statement? You don't have to do that!

```
SELECT genus, species, count(ID_Indiv) as NoOfIndiv, sum(weight)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY  genus, species;
```

`GROUP BY` will take care of making `{genus, species}` pair unique within each group.

Comment: Thank you!!! I had used this nested statement to count how many unique combinations are there (currently), and thought I have to extend it now to get the additional columns (count, and sum). Excellent - thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your attempt was very close... so I'm not sure if I'm oversimplifying the issue... but shouldn't just a simple `GROUP BY` do what you are looking for?

```
SELECT 
  genus, 
  species, 
  COUNT(*) AS NoOfIndiv, 
  SUM(weight) as TotalWeight
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 
  genus, 
  species
```